# How to get the source URL of http 301 redirection in PHP with out passing any parameter?

Tags: php, apache, http-redirect

I need to get the source URL of HTTP redirection. For example, I have a primary domain [www.test.com](http://www.test.com), and also I have another domain [www.testredirect.com](http://www.testredirect.com). If we go to [www.testredirect.com](http://www.testredirect.com) it will redirect to [www.test.com](http://www.test.com). I need to run a small script if the main domain is loaded by the redirection. How I can achieve this? Is there any way without passing any parameters in the redirection?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure may be this will work. It will give you the URL of the page that redirected to the current page

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf('www.testredirect.com') !== -1) {
  // the page was loaded by a redirect from www.testredirect.com
  // run your script here
}
```